# How can the Build Agent name to TFS Build Notification email?

Tags: tfs, notifications, tfsbuild

I would like to include the name of the build agent in my build notification emails. Something like:

> Ran for 5.3 minutes (MyController - Controller, **Agent01 - Build
>   Agent**), completed at Thu 01/12/2017 12:05 PM

Answer (score 0):

You cannot customize the notification email, but you can [customize the build](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms400688%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) to send the email with format and content you like.

Consider using the [TFS Build Extensions](https://github.com/tfsbuildextensions/CustomActivities/wiki) to speed up your work.